# Changing UIView frame size does not change UITableview frame origin y

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I have added a UIView on top of a `tableviewcontroller` in IB by dragging and dropping then I have assigned and `IBoutlet` to that `UIView`.

Problem is I have a uilabel that is dynamically changing its size , so if uilabel is short I want to make the tableview closer otherwise tableview should be not that close so I can show a very long label.

So I try to change the frame of the `uiview` that is on top of `tableview` uiview changes its frame size but tableview stays stable there.

I wan to make `uitableview` go down when I make `UIview` frame size height bigger

```
if ([[self agenda] getMeetingTime] != nil) {
        descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, dateLabel.frame.origin.y + dateLabel.bounds.size.height+15, self.view.frame.size.width-75, 150)];
        descriptionLabel.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:96/256.0 green:96/256.0 blue:96/256.0 alpha:1.0];
        descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:15.0f];
        descriptionLabel.text =[[self agenda] getMeetingTime];
        descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        descriptionLabel.tag=PopulateTag;

        //Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(709,999);

        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:descriptionLabel.font
                                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                  lineBreakMode:descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode];

        //adjust the label the the new height.
        CGRect newFrame = descriptionLabel.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
        descriptionLabel.frame=newFrame;


        if ( expectedLabelSize.height>70) {

            self.upperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperView.frame.size.width, self.upperView.frame.size.height+expectedLabelSize.height+20);

        }
        else
        {
            self.upperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperView.frame.size.width, self.upperView.frame.size.height+expectedLabelSize.height);
        }


        [ self.upperView addSubview: descriptionLabel];


    }


    //black line
    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + descriptionLabel.bounds.size.height+15, descriptionLabel.frame.size.width+50, 1)];
    line.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:164/256.0 green:165/256.0 blue:160/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    line.tag=PopulateTag;

    [self.upperView addSubview:line];

      //this does not work pushes whole view down
     //self.restOfView.frame=CGRectMake(10, line.frame.origin.y + line.bounds.size.height+1, self.upperView.frame.size.width, 600);
    [restOfView reloadData];
```

On IB:

[image]

[image]

This is what happens:

[image]

Tableview needs go down here

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't believe you should be subclassing a `UITableViewController` to achieve what you want. A `UITableViewController` is useful when you know that your view will only contain a `UITableView`, in my opinion adding anything else to one defeats the purpose.

To solve your problem though, in the bottom of your code snippet uncomment out the line where you change the frame of your tableview (assuming `self.restOfView` is your tableView) and instead of call `[self.restOfView reloadData]` call:

```
[self.restOfView setNeedsDisplay];
```

`reloadData` just calls the tableView data source methods again, `setNeedsDisplay` redraws the object. I think that will work.

Comment: I am not subclassing uitableviewcontroller, just needed a uiview on top of tableview, just adding  `[self.restOfView setNeedsDisplay]`  didnt change anything, changing self.restOfView frame messes up whole view plus uiview changes too.

Comment: Ok my bad, what is your tableview object?

Comment: I mean its a tableview controller in .h `EventDetailsViewController : UITableViewController`  I just use `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *restOfView;` to control tableview(I could have use self.tableview too)

Comment: Yeah reading your answer again sorry, I am subclassing `Uitableviewcontroller` my bad

Comment: OK thats definitely your problem because the tableView in a UITableViewController isn't meant to be resized...check out this post though there's a solution there if you really don't want to make that change, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350686/how-to-resize-uitableview-in-uitableviewcontroller-with-section-header