# How to implement search bar in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

**Context**: I am building an app in `Swift` that mostly consists of a `UITableView`. Each cell consists of four labels, the data for each is pulled from core data. I've used [apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html) as a basis for the tableview, and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt8BNhpEAok&t) for core data handling. The final feature I'm working on is search and I'm struggling.

**Problem:** The problem I'm having is that most tutorials for searching tableviews seem to be structured around adding search to a tableview that is connected as an outlet within a UIViewController. I've followed the apple tutorial so my tableview is set up within UITableViewController. I'm essentially stuck on the following issue: how can I implement a search bar within UITableViewController that filters cells based on their primary label (which is pulled from core data)?

Comment: What have you tried? If you post some code, perhaps we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Using a UITableViewController is a little trickier than a regular UIViewController. I'd recommend switching now while the refactor is still pretty easy. If you want to continue with the UITableViewController, you need to resize the table view to make room at the top for the search bar.

This post talks about resizing the table view: [How to resize UITableView in UITableViewController with section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350686/how-to-resize-uitableview-in-uitableviewcontroller-with-section-header)

After you have the table view out of the way, you can make a new view and add it to the top of the screen for your search bar.

```
private var searchBarWrapperView: UIView!

private var _searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height - 64)

    _searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    _searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    searchBarWrapperView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 44))

    searchBarWrapperView.addSubview(_searchController.searchBar)

    tableView.superview!.addSubview(searchBarWrapperView)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // filter the data for the search and then reload
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```